# How to get an array by JSON and how to set this return value to a modal form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, modal-dialog

My Ajax code:

```
$("a#edit").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    //alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getdata.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'JSON',
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

My php code:

```
if ($_REQUEST['id'] != "") 
{
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql = "select * from visit_reports WHERE visit_planner_id='$id'";

    $query = sqlsrv_query( $link, $sql);
    while($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

In Firebug, the array I get:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1.0000
    [visit_planner_id] => 230338
    [bi_staff_present_name] => BI staff present name
    [bi_staff_trial_function] => BI staff trial function
)
```

How can I use this array value into my specific input field of modal form?

Comment: Why not use jQuery to loop through each element in array?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, Why not print JSON instead of array?

`echo json_encode($data);`

Now, you can parse it easily from your ajax code.

```
success:function(result){
       var json = $.parseJSON(result);
       var id = json.id; // 1.0000
       var visit_planner_id= json.visit_planner_id; // 230338
       // so on..
}
```